# How to detect the main content block of a website?

Tags: javascript, css

I've always wondered how the "read mode" extensions know exactly where the main content is.

If every webpage out there had its main content in a div marked with the id of `#content` or something. But is there a way to know which div is the wrapper for the main content?

#### Here's what I want to do

I want to create a script where I inject a text box to the right of any webpage so that I can take notes (Eloquent is an example chrome extension that does this - but it doesn't push the content, it makes the textbox dragable instead - don't like it). Then the notes I take would go to my mongo databases (all done)

But when I add the textbox to the page, I would love to push the main content to te side.

Here's a screenshot of what I have so far

[image]

As I said, if I want this to just run on wikipedia for example I could hardcode the element id/class. **But is there a way to check for the main content regardless how the developers might have labled it**

Comment: If the webpage is actually trying to be good about accessibility, it will probably have a [`<main/>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) which indicates the actual meat of the page.

Comment: @zero298 I remember trying that out but no luck. I just tried it in Wikipedia for example and nope.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it's kind of a mixed bag.  It looks like Wikipedia uses the aria [`role="main"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Main_role) to indicate main content which is also a possibility.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail of how you would like the textbox to work and how you have it working at the moment? Do you want to be able to click on something and have the text box appear in that area, pushing the original text to one side, or...?

Comment: There is not going to be a solution that will work with every site. If there is a limited number of sites you want to support, you might be able to make rules for each one.

Comment: Before the <main> element was invented, the HTML5 spec editor Ian Hickson argued strongly that the element was unnecessary, and that the start of the main content block was inevitably the first non-hidden body content not in an <aside>, <nav>, <header> or <footer> element, so that approach maybe could be used in the absence of an explicitly marked main.   I don't know if read mode extensions do that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to be absolutely sure for every page on the internet.  There are mechanisms to try and signal what is the "main" bit of a page.  Two of the "main" ways to do it are

1. The [`<main/>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

> The HTML  element represents the dominant content of the 
> of a document. The main content area consists of content that is
> directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document,
> or the central functionality of an application.

2. [`role="main"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Main_role)

> The main landmark role is used to indicate the primary content of a
> document. The main content area consists of content that is directly
> related to or expands upon the central topic of a document, or the
> central functionality of an application.

However, websites aren't breaking any real rules and will still render in most browsers if they don't include either of these.  They are mostly ways to help users that require screen readers be able to view content.

You mentioned you were looking at how Wikipedia does it and they use the `role="main"` mechanism.